# Checkbox formula not working

Tags: formula-field, checkbox, if

I am trying to select a checkbox if, "Connected" is in the disposition and the call sentiment field does not have "Gatekeeper".

My formula isn't working:

```
IF(
AND(
    CONTAINS(SalesLoft1__Call_Disposition__c , "Connected"),
    CONTAINS ( SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c, ""),
    NOT(CONTAINS( SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c , "Gatekeeper"))
)
,
TRUE,
FALSE
)
```

Comment: Why do you have `CONTAINS ( SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c, "")`?. That isn't included in your description of what you want your formula field to do. Also, `IF(<boolean expression>, true, false)` can _always_ be simplified to `<boolean condition>`. The `IF()` here isn't required.

Comment: Ah - the reason I added that is that if the sentiment field = blank  & the  disposition = Connected, I don't want it to select the checkbox. I only want it to select the checkbox if the disposition = Connected and the Sentiment is not equal to Gatekeeper or blank

Comment: What are the data types for these two fields? That may have an effect on why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this -

```
AND(
    CONTAINS(SalesLoft1__Call_Disposition__c , "Connected"),
    NOT(CONTAINS( SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c , "Gatekeeper"))
)
```

IF function is not required if the return type is a checkbox, you can directly use your condition as it will return either true or false.

Comment: Thanks! It's still not selecting the checkbox for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think we need more information here. Can you please mention the field data type? Are these picklist or normal text fields.?

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment (and as Gaurav states in their answer), the `IF()` isn't required here. That shouldn't be causing you any issues here, but less typing is generally better.

Beyond that, a few important points are:

- `CONTAINS()` is *case-sensitive*, so if your disposition is actuallly "connected", then this will return false
- To check for blank values, you should be using `ISBLANK()`
- Double check to make sure that your formula is set to "Treat blank values as blanks" (and not treating them as zeros)

So, assuming your test string values are properly cased and your blank handling is appropriately set, the formula you're looking for should be

```
AND(
    CONTAINS(SalesLoft1__Call_Disposition__c, "Connected"),
    NOT(ISBLANK(SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c)),
    NOT(CONTAINS(SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c, "Gatekeeper"))
)
```

Your previous attempt failed because you were checking if `SalesLoft1__Call_Sentiment__c` *was the empty string* instead of checking if it *is not blank*.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful! The checkbox still isn't selecting for some odd reason.

Comment: @user123970 In that case, it'll be helpful if you edited your question to add the exact values (literally copy/paste it) for the record that you're seeing the issue with.